# WPF issue with button background image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have my wpf button as follows

```
<Button x:Name="helpButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="552,201,95,726" Width="32" Height="32" BorderThickness="0" Click="helpButton_Click">
  <Button.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/help-icon1.png"></ImageBrush>  
  </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

On window load I am able to see the image perfectly but when I hover the mouse I am not able to see the image

[image]

So can some one help me

Comment: You have to set the whole `Template` not only the `Background`

Comment: You can as well set the button content as image if you don't mind the button background to remain standard button like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more sensible approach to start would be by using `<Button.Template>` instead of `<Button.Background>`

```
<Button x:Name="helpButton">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Image Source="/Images/help-icon1.png" Width="32" Height="32"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Additionally style the button border with for example a hover effect with `Trigger` and `Setter`

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"></Setter>
        <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
     </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

which you will add like so:

```
<Button x:Name="helpButton" Height="35">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Name="buttonBorder"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Image Source="/Images/help-icon1.png" Width="32" Height="32"/>
             </Border>
             <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                     <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                     <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                 </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks Jim the most efficient one :)

Answer (score 0):

It is really strange why it is not possible to see image when button is hovered. Default style always shows `Content`(in your case, image). So I suggest you just use default style for your button:

```
<Button Style="{ x:Null}">
   <Image Source="/images/images.jpg"></Image>
</Button>
```

Or just override behavior of template when mouse is over button:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <!--Do not do any actions here to see your image-->      
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In this case, there is no actions when mouse is over your button.

Comment: He is not settings the image as content.